# different rights for different users in same directory on apache server

Tags: apache, webdav

Is it possible to restrict differently the user access in a directory on an apache server?

For example that user foo can read and write a file and another user bar can only read?

**Update**: what I tried so far

```
<Directory /var/www/html/uploads>
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "WebDAV access"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/html/uploads/.passwdfile
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    <LimitExcept GET>
        Require user testUserGet testUserPut
    </LimitExcept>
    <LimitExcept PUT>
        Require user testUserPut
    </LimitExcept>
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

However, I know can `PUT` stuff into `uploads` just by specifying a valid user (I guess that's due to `Require valid-user`).
What I need is that testUserGet can only perform `GET` and testUserPut only `PUT` and `GET`.

Comment: Do you mean FTP or SSH access; or do you use some PHP to let users upload data? Because apache can't create files.

Comment: thought of PUT,GET.. HTTP and WebDAV

Comment: There is an example of that in the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html#example

Comment: @Gerben: Thanks for the hint. What I was thinking of is having several `LimitExcept` blocks in one `Location` block, e.g. `<LimitExcept GET POST> Require user user1</LimitExcept> <LimitExcept GET> Require user user2</LimitExcept>`.. but like this I get the same rights for both, i.e. user2 can also POST.

Comment: You can add multiple names to a require, `Require user userid [userid] ...`, so e.g. `Require user user1 user2 user3`

Comment: @Gerben: Correct, but I want (need) the users to have different rights.

Comment: I know. You solution of multiple LimitExcept block should do that I think. I just wanted to provide some additional info.

Comment: old post - but I too am trying to achieve same results and this did not work with the `<LimitExcept PUT>` to allow upload only and not view the folder or file content - did this work for you @ezdazuzene

Comment: @BarclayVision: Indeed.. long time ago. I actually did not achieve it. Sorry, can't help you.